# Power BI Rest API - JS - Programatically Setting Visual Level Filter Error

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to build a web application with Buttons to filter Visuals from a Power BI report.
[Documentation that I am following](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters), I am able to get the visual onto my application but when I set a filter using **Visual.setFilters()** method it is throwing me an error saying **"Setting visual level filters is not supported."**.

**Visual in Web Application:**
[image]

**Error from Developer Console:**
[image]

**Code:**
 ` var accessToken = '@ViewBag.AccessToken';

```
    if (!accessToken || accessToken == "") {
        return;
    }

    var basicFilter = {
        $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
        target: {
            table: "Products",
            column: "Product"
        },
        operator: "In",
        values: ["Sova"],
        filterType: 'BasicFilter'
    }


    // Get models. models contains enums that can be used.
    var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
    // Gross Margin Tile
    var embedConfiguration = {
        type: 'visual',
        accessToken: accessToken,
        id: 'REPORT_ID',
        pageName: 'ReportSection',
        visualName:'VisualContainer7',
        embedUrl: 'REPORT_EMBEDD_URL',
        dashboardId: 'DASHBOARD_ID',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
        filters: []
    };
    var $tileContainer = $('#grossMarginTile');
    var grossMarginTile = powerbi.embed($tileContainer.get(0), embedConfiguration);
    grossMarginTile.setFilters([basicFilter])
        .catch(errors => {
            console.log(errors)
        });`
```

**I am new to this, any help will be appreciated, what am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an older version of the JS SDK, update to the latest and this will be resolved.
I also noticed that you do visual embedding but you have dashboardId in the embedComfiguration, This is unnecessary